# li a:nth-child with variable from Django doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am currently working on a personal blog in Django to get better at web programming, but I have encountered a slight problem. My idea was to make the webpage able to know which menu element is the active one, passing an argument from the views.py and to the template. Thus, I am here to ask why that might be so.

This is my template:

```
{% block menu %}

        <style> li a:nth-child({{ active }}) { text-decoration: underline; } </style>

    <li><div id="title"><span>{</span> <a href="#">Title</a> <span>}</span></div></li>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>

{% endblock menu %}
```

And here is my views.py (for the specific page):

```
def detail(request, blog_id):
    blog = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'blogs/post.html', {'blog': blog, 'active': 1})
```

I have tried targetting the nth-child of the li's, but that didn't work either. I have also tried putting in fixed numbers as a parameter for the nth-child. Alas, to no avail.

Can anyone help me? Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: give each href an id, and pass the id to the template.  Write the style code with that id as a variable

Comment: No, it didn't work. I see that the id tag was indeed brought into Firefox from the template, but it simply doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here: `nth-child` looks for the n-th child element in a group. Your code as it is currently would style the `n`th `a` element inside a `li` tag - but there's only ever one `a` in each `li`. You need to target the `li`:

```
li:nth-child({{ active }}) a { text-decoration: underline; }
```

You also need to make sure that the `li` items have nothing else alongside them (including `style` tags), as this will mess up the counter. The template code you've posted above is incomplete (we can't see the outer `ul`/`ol`) but if there are other elements inside it then that is a problem.

That said, I don't think that this is the best approach - dynamic inline styling is not a robust, maintainable solution. A much more common pattern is to add an `active` class to the active list item, and then have styling for this in your core (static) CSS. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665514/django-highlight-navigation-based-on-current-page) for some ideas on how to implement that.