# Concatenate strings together in template if statement

Tags: python, django

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665514/django-highlight-navigation-based-on-current-page) and my code looked like this:

html:

```
<li {% if request.path == '/groups/{{ group.id }}/' %}class="active"{% endif %} ><a href="{% url 'detail' group.id %}">Link</a></li>
```

The only problem is that `/groups/{{ group.id }}/` obviously turn into:

`/groups/{{ group.id }}/`

not

`/groups/1/`

[that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates) will end up being a lot of code if type it for the other 10 links on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding the url, use the `url` tag with `as`

```
{% url 'my_group_url_name' group.id as group_url %}
{% if request.path == group_url %}
```