# Highlight dropdown menu in django

Tags: python, django

I have a template with a dropdown menu. Dropdown contains several options (read links). When one of them is chosen I want the dropdown to be highlighted. To do this I want to check if request path is one of the dropdown menu options.

I.e. say my links inside the dropdown have the urls url1, url2, url2, and I want to do this in template:

```
{% if request.path in [url1, url2, url3] %}
    highlight dropdown menu
{% endif %}
```

What is the best approach to the problem?

Comment: This is very close: [Navigation in django](http://stackoverflow.com/a/477719/63011). Have a look at this post for the implementation details: [A Django template tag for the current active page](http://gnuvince.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/a-django-template-tag-for-the-current-active-page/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) and use it to highlight the dropdown:

```
@register.simple_tag
def check(url):
    for elem in url_list:
        if elem in url:
            return true
    return false
```

and then apply it to your template:

```
<select {% if check request.get_full_path %}class="highlighted"{% endif %} >
....
</select>
```

Comment: I used your idea, but instead of simple_tag I used a filter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using Samuele's answer I created a filter like this one:

```
@register.filter
def check(url, url_list, delimeter=","):
    url_list = url_list.split(delimeter)
    for item in url_list:
        if url in item:
            return True
    return False
```

Then in my template I use the following code:

```
{% if request.path|check:"url1,url2" %}
    # here goes the html code
{% endif %}
```