# Highlight Active Navigation: django 1.4.2

Tags: python, django, templates, navigation

I am trying to set a base django template whose navigation elements will highlight when they are active. I have tried the following posts to create a templatetag to append an active value to the markup:

[Blog Post](http://ilostmynotes.blogspot.com/2010/03/django-current-active-page-highlighting.html)

[110j's answer to this Stack Overflow Question (not the accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340888/navigation-in-django)

Both are suggesting using a templatetag to check if user is on selected page, then use that to add an active value to the navigation in the template. However, I get an `AttributeError` saying that: `'str' object has no attribute 'path'`. After searching, I cannot figure out how to remedy this problem..

How do I achieve the most de-coupled method of highlighting active navigation on Django 1.4.2 + python 2.7? Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I had the same problem. The problem is in the `settings.py` file configuration. Try adding this after `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.core.context_processors.request',
                               'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                               'django.core.context_processors.static',
                              )
```