# How to add a class ACTIVE by using django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

```
<div class="menu-top" style="width:715px;">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li>
      <a href="/link1"
      {% if request.path == '/phylosophy' %}class="active"{% endif %}>
      philosophy
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/link2"><u>{% trans 'product' %}</u></a></li>
    <li><a href="/link3"><u>{% trans 'contact' %}</u></a></li>
    <li><a href="/link4"><u>{% trans 'news' %}</u></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to add the class .active to the  tag. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django dynamically get view url and check if its the current page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047251/django-dynamically-get-view-url-and-check-if-its-the-current-page)

Comment: Did you try printing `{{ request.path }}` to check if its value is really equal to what you are comparing to?

Answer (score 2):

Normally Django appends `/` to the URLs, so it might be the case of changing to:

```
{% if request.path == '/phylosophy/' %}class="active"{% endif %}>
```

**Extra:**

The thing with this approach is that, if you have a deeper URL like `/phylosophy/list/`, you may still want to keep the `active` class, so what I usually do is creating a templatetag called `startswith`:

```
@register.filter('startswith')
def startswith(text, starts):
    if isinstance(text, basestring):
        return text.startswith(starts)
    return False
```

And then use it like:

```
<li{% if request.path|startswith:'/phylosophy/' %} class="active"{% endif %}>
```

**PS:**

In case `request.path` is empty when you print it, you might need to add it to your context processors (`django.template.context_processors.request`), example:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': (
            PROJECT_DIR.child('templates'),
        ),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG
        }
    },
]
```