# Django custom block tags

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to create a block in the code for a custom template tag?

The motivation is that my navigation bar currently looks like this:

```
{% url 'index_url' as index %}
{% url 'about_url' as about %}
...
{% block nav-index %}
  <div class="{% active request index %}">
    <a href="{{index}}"/>Home</a>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
...
```

Here `{% active ... %}` is a custom tag based on the idea in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477719/274460).  With another custom tag, it's fairly easy to cut this down to this:

```
{% block nav-index %}{% navlink request 'index_url' 'Home' %}{% endblock %}
```

I'd ideally like to cut it down to this:

```
{% navlink request 'nav-index' 'index_url' 'Home' %}
```

but to do that would require being able to create a block in the code for a custom tag.  Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want that block for. Do you mean that it is going into a nav-index block defined by the parent template?

Comment: This is all in base.html - the idea is that another template can extend base.html and override the block to add its children etc.

Comment: You should have a look at the source code for Tag & filters, this will give you a nice idea of how you could achieve what you want. Especially URLNode (line 465) and url tag (line 1369)

Comment: See the answer I linked for an explanation of how it works.

Comment: @TanguySerrat: I've had a look, but I'm not sure how it helps.  How does this help me to add a block programmatically?